# How to deserialize JSON with JSON.NET with convert error

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am using an API written by one of the in house web developers in PHP. I am writing an application in C#  using JSON.net to deserialize the json. This API is used to retrieve customer information from a database. If the user exists the json returned is

```
{
  "success": true,
  "id": "21",
  "msg": "",
  "info": {       
    "FirstName": "name",
    "LastName": "name",        
  }
}
```

and this gets deserialized to a class like this

```
public class Json
{           
    public bool Success { get; set; }           
    public object Id { get; set; }         
    public string Msg { get; set; }
    public Info Info { get; set; }           
}

public class Info
{       
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }        
}
```

This works perfectly fine.

Otherwise if the user does not exist then I receive this

```
{
  "success": false,
  "id": false,
  "msg": "User does not exists in databse",
  "info": false
}
```

If I try to deserialize this then I get

```
{"Error converting value False to type 'Info'. Path 'info', line 1, position 79."}
```

Is there anyway to get the second json type to deserialize to the same class without this error or do I need to make a new class for the different json.

Comment: Returning a boolean OR an object is a questionable API design. It should probably return `null` instead of `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rob's comment is correct in that this is poor API design and `info` should return `null` if nothing exists.

If this is outside your control, however, you can use a custom `JsonConverter` to check if the type of `info` is a `bool` and return `null`, however deserialize as normal.

```
public class InfoConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Boolean ? null : serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To trigger the converter, just add the `JsonConverter` attribute to your `Info` property:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(InfoConverter))]
public Info Info
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

This will execute the converter automatically when you deserialise, check if the type of the input is a boolean and return null if it is, or deserialise if it isn't.

This is assuming that any bool received in `info` means that the user doesn't exist. If this isn't the case, just update the `ReadJson` method as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I currently don't have a compiler, so I can't check it, but maybe you could add an implicit conversion operator to `Info`:

```
public class Info
{       
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator Info(bool b)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But even if that works, it would be beyond hacky.